# Pandas 'lists' in a row/frame

Tags: python, pandas

Alright I've got a weird one --

```
     ctry_list
0  RU,RU,RU,RU
1          NaN
2          NaN
[Finished in 8.3s]
```

I need to get the ctry_list into their own separate row -

```
     ctry_list
0          RU
1          RU
2          RU
3          RU
[Finished in 8.3s]
```

I tried this -

```
frame2 = frame1[['ctry_list']]
#print frame2.head(10)
s = frame2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['ctry_list']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
s.name = 'list'
frame3 = frame2.drop('ctry_list', axis=1).join(s)
print frame3.head(10)
```

But that just gives me this

```
          list
0  RU,RU,RU,RU
0        BR,BR
0          ,US
0          US,
0     US,US,US
0           ,,
0  RU,RU,RU,RU
0        BR,BR
0          ,US
0          US,
[Finished in 8.2s]
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ctry_list column contains strings with comma-separated values, then this works for your example:

`frame1['ctry_list'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack()`